# PHP Checking datetime format using preg_match and checkdate wrong result

Tags: php, validation, datetime, preg-match

I want to validate datetime format using preg_match() and checkdate() function.
My format is "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss".
What wrong with my code?

```
function checkDatetime($dateTime){
    $matches = array();
    if(preg_match("/^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4}) ([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/", $dateTime, $matches)){
        print_r($matches); echo "<br>";
        $dd = trim($matches[1]);
        $mm = trim($matches[2]);
        $yy = trim($matches[3]);
        return checkdate($mm, $dd, $yy); // <- Problem here?
    }else{
        echo "wrong format<br>";
        return false;
    }    
} 

//wrong result
if(checkDatetime("12-21-2000 03:04:00")){
    echo "checkDatetime true<br>";
}else{
    echo "checkDatetime false<br>";
}

//correct result
if(checkdate("12", "21", "2000")){
    echo "checkdate true<br>";
}else{
    echo "checkdate false<br>";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => 12-21-2000 03:04:00 [1] => 12 [2] => 21 [3] => 2000 [4] => 03 [5] => 04 [6] => 00 )

checkDatetime false

checkdate true
```

Comment: `12-21-2000` in your definition stands for "2000 year, 21 month, 12 day", which of course is falsy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(checkDatetime("12-21-2000 03:04:00"))` leads to

```
$dd = 12
$mm = 21
$yy = 2000
```

You then call `return checkdate($mm, $dd, $yy);`, which is equivalent to `return checkdate(21, 12, 2000);`

It's fairly clear that `$mm` can't be 21, but I can't say if you're passing the wrong format to `checkDatetime` or if you're parsing it wrong in the regex.